# How to remove folding shower bench?

Tags: bathroom

I have a shower bench just like the below. The cups at the wall are starting to seperate and there is a scum buildup around the edges, and most certainly behind. How do I remove the bench to do a deep clean and tighten?

[image]

Comment: If there are no obvious screws to remove in the dadoes where the bench arms fold up, have you looked for screws at the bottom of the "cups"? Likely there are set screws holding it to mounts attached to the wall.